# Heroku Datomic Buildpack throws "Device "eth1" does not exist"

Tags: heroku, clojure, datomic, buildpack

I'm trying to deploy a free Datomic transactor on Heroku using Postgres as a backing store, so I followed the steps outlined in this [Heroku Buildpack for Datomic](https://elements.heroku.com/buildpacks/opengrail/heroku-buildpack-datomic) and provisiond a hobby-dev Postgres resource.

When I deploy my uberjar, my dynos crash with these logs:

```
Starting process with command `/app/scripts/start-datomic.sh`
2017-12-30T15:58:01.753404+00:00 heroku[datomic.1]: State changed from starting to up
2017-12-30T15:58:04.332538+00:00 app[datomic.1]: Device "eth1" does not exist.
2017-12-30T15:58:04.335756+00:00 app[datomic.1]: sed: can't read /app/scripts/transactor.properties: No such file or directory
2017-12-30T15:58:04.350931+00:00 app[datomic.1]: Launching with Java options -server -Xms256m -Xmx2g  -Ddatomic.printConnectionInfo=false
2017-12-30T15:58:04.363382+00:00 app[datomic.1]: Picked up JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS: -Xmx300m -Xss512k -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8  -Djava.rmi.server.useCodebaseOnly=true
2017-12-30T15:58:05.131605+00:00 app[web.1]: Setting JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS defaults based on dyno size. Custom settings will override them.
2017-12-30T15:58:05.138147+00:00 app[web.1]: Picked up JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS: -Xmx300m -Xss512k -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8  -Djava.rmi.server.useCodebaseOnly=true
2017-12-30T15:58:02.309543+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `java -cp target/build/app.jar clojure.main -m character-sheet.core "server"`
2017-12-30T15:58:18.500110+00:00 app[datomic.1]: Critical failure, cannot continue: Error starting transactor
2017-12-30T15:58:18.514594+00:00 app[datomic.1]: java.lang.Exception: 'protocol' property not set
2017-12-30T15:58:18.514694+00:00 app[datomic.1]:    at datomic.transactor$ensure_args.invokeStatic(transactor.clj:111)
2017-12-30T15:58:18.514767+00:00 app[datomic.1]:    at datomic.transactor$ensure_args.invoke(transactor.clj:100)
2017-12-30T15:58:18.514837+00:00 app[datomic.1]:    at datomic.transactor$run$fn__13229.invoke(transactor.clj:347)
2017-12-30T15:58:18.517285+00:00 app[datomic.1]:    at clojure.core$binding_conveyor_fn$fn__5476.invoke(core.clj:2022)
2017-12-30T15:58:18.517345+00:00 app[datomic.1]:    at clojure.lang.AFn.call(AFn.java:18)
2017-12-30T15:58:18.517404+00:00 app[datomic.1]:    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
2017-12-30T15:58:18.517463+00:00 app[datomic.1]:    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
2017-12-30T15:58:18.517523+00:00 app[datomic.1]:    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
2017-12-30T15:58:18.517584+00:00 app[datomic.1]:    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

The two things that stand out are: `Device "eth1" does not exist` and that the `transactor.properties` file is missing.

How do I add this?

`Procfile` contents:

```
datomic: /app/scripts/start-datomic.sh
web: java -cp target/build/app.jar clojure.main -m my-project.core
```

Comment: I suspect the "eth1" error is related to Heroku Spaces, which is only available on Heroku Enteprise :/

Comment: The sed error seems more significant. Did you add a `scripts/transactor.properties` file to your Git repo?

Comment: Where does app/scripts get populated from? It seems to come from /vendor in the buildpack. I couldn't find the docs stating how these paths would be merged